# Gmail auto login and error message python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, python-webbrowser

I am trying to login to the blogger site, but first I have to enter the Gmail account. I entered it, but an error message appears, "This browser or app may not be secure"
can you help me with this error.
this is my code

```
from statistics import mean
import pandas as pd
from selenium_stealth import stealth
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import pyautogui
import time
print("ready?")
print("loading.......................................")
df = pd.read_excel("Moaaz.xlsx","Moaaz")
email = "sisoasn81@gmail.com"
password = "1*1#36@$%anz"
name = df["Name"].values.tolist()
website = df["Website"].values.tolist()
phone = df["Phone"].values.tolist()
logo = df["Logo"].values.tolist()
firm_map = df["Firm map"].values.tolist()

driver = webdriver.Chrome("D:\\driver\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.delete_all_cookies()
driver.get('https://www.blogger.com/blog/posts/3793019451239403430')
time.sleep(2)
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_id('identifierId').send_keys(email)
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element_by_id('identifierNext').click()
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element_by_id('password').send_keys(password)
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_id('passwordNext').click()
time.sleep(10)

for s in range(len(name)):
    #click new post
    driver.find_element_by_class_name('U26fgb O0WRkf zZhnYe e3Duub C0oVfc zr7Fj zFM5pd M9Bg4d').click()
    #enter name dog
    driver.find_element_by_class_name('whsOnd zHQkBf').send_keys(name[s])
    #convert to html view
    pyautogui.leftClick(627, 707)
    pyautogui.leftClick(455, 206)
    pyautogui.leftClick(149, 279)
    driver.stop_client()
```

Comment: REMOVE PASSWORD AND EMAIL shown in the code! sensible info

Comment: no my brother this is fake information just for show the code, thk u for care about my info.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [undetected-chromedriver](https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver), also works for cloudflare bypass and google login

```
pip install undetected-chromedriver
```

Your optimized code with `undetected-chromedriver`, `WebdriverWait` and `By.`

```
import pandas as pd
import pyautogui
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

print("ready?")
print("loading.......................................")
df = pd.read_excel("Moaaz.xlsx","Moaaz")
email = ""
password = ""
name = df["Name"].values.tolist()
website = df["Website"].values.tolist()
phone = df["Phone"].values.tolist()
logo = df["Logo"].values.tolist()
firm_map = df["Firm map"].values.tolist()

driver = uc.Chrome(use_subprocess=True)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
driver.delete_all_cookies()
driver.get('https://www.blogger.com/blog/posts/3793019451239403430')
driver.maximize_window()


wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'identifierId'))).send_keys(email)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'identifierNext'))).click()
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'password'))).send_keys(password)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'passwordNext'))).click()


for s in range(len(name)):
    #click new post
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'U26fgb O0WRkf zZhnYe e3Duub C0oVfc zr7Fj zFM5pd M9Bg4d'))).click()
    #enter name dog
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'whsOnd zHQkBf'))).send_keys(name[s])
    #convert to html view
    pyautogui.leftClick(627, 707)
    pyautogui.leftClick(455, 206)
    pyautogui.leftClick(149, 279)
    driver.stop_client()
```

Comment: driver = uc.Chrome(use_subprocess=True)
  File "C:\Users\dsoky\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\lib\site-packages\undetected_chromedriver\__init__.py", line 339, in __init__
    browser_executable_path or find_chrome_executable()
  File "C:\Users\dsoky\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\lib\site-packages\undetected_chromedriver\__init__.py", line 696, in find_chrome_executable
    candidates.add(os.sep.join((item, subitem, "chrome.exe")))
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, NoneType found

Comment: this error shown

Comment: try deleting `use_subprocess=True`

Comment: File "C:\Users\dsoky\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\lib\site-packages\undetected_chromedriver\__init__.py", line 696, in find_chrome_executable
    candidates.add(os.sep.join((item, subitem, "chrome.exe")))
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, NoneType found

Comment: https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver/issues/505 problem got solved there, put back use_subprocess=True

Comment: it open and after some time colse the browser and show this error self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\dsoky\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=99.0.4844.82)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
        Ordinal0 [0x01289943+2595139]

Answer (score -2):

You need to disable the web security with adding some options to your driver.

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--disable-web-security")
options.add_argument("--allow-running-insecure-content")

driver = webdriver.Chrome("D:\\driver\\chromedriver.exe",options = options)
driver.get('https://www.blogger.com/blog/posts/3793019451239403430')
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but your edit isn’t what I meant.